# Ionic 2 Http POST Method ERROR

Tags: json, http, angular, ionic2

Hi Im going to call http post method using ionic 2.but in the response always im getting error.can any one help me.

this is my json type

```
{
“username”:”user”,
"password":”pass"
}
```

This is my code

```
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(http: Http, nav: NavController) {
    this.http = http;
    this.makePostRequest();
  }

  makePostRequest() {

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.post('url',
      JSON.stringify({ username: 'admin', password: 'a' }),
      { headers: headers })
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe((res) => console.log("res", res));

  }

}
```

error Log

```
4     236980   log      DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER, 1437, ms
5     237420   group    EXCEPTION: [object Object]
6     237426   error    EXCEPTION: [object Object]
7     237431   error    STACKTRACE:
8     237433   error    
9     237435   groupEnd 
10    237525   error    Uncaught #<Response>, http://192.168.1.13:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js, Line: 7834
```

How can i solve this.?

I added the error handling

this is the log in browser

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://url/login/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
app.bundle.js:67773 error Response_body: ProgressEventbubbles: falsecancelBubble: falsecancelable: falsecurrentTarget: XMLHttpRequestonabort: undefinedonerror: undefinedonload: undefinedonloadend: undefinedonloadstart: undefinedonprogress: undefinedonreadystatechange: undefinedontimeout: undefinedreadyState: 0response: ""responseText: ""responseType: ""responseURL: ""responseXML: nullstatus: 0statusText: ""timeout: 0upload: XMLHttpRequestUploadonabort: nullonerror: nullonload: nullonloadend: nullonloadstart: nullonprogress: nullontimeout: null__proto__: XMLHttpRequestUploadconstructor: XMLHttpRequestUpload()arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 0name: "XMLHttpRequestUpload"prototype: XMLHttpRequestUploadconstructor: XMLHttpRequestUpload()arguments: nullcaller: nulllength: 0name: "XMLHttpRequestUpload"prototype: XMLHttpRequestUpload__proto__: XMLHttpRequestEventTarget()<function scope>onabort: (...)onerror: (...)onload: (...)onloadend: (...)onloadstart: (...)onprogress: (...)ontimeout: (...)Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "XMLHttpRequestUpload"__proto__: XMLHttpRequestEventTarget__proto__: XMLHttpRequestEventTarget()<function scope>onabort: (...)onerror: (...)onload: (...)onloadend: (...)onloadstart: (...)onprogress: (...)ontimeout: (...)Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "XMLHttpRequestUpload"__proto__: XMLHttpRequestEventTargetwithCredentials: false__proto__: XMLHttpRequestdefaultPrevented: falseeventPhase: 0isTrusted: trueisTrusted: truelengthComputable: falseloaded: 0path: Array[0]returnValue: truesrcElement: XMLHttpRequesttarget: XMLHttpRequesttimeStamp: 2726.8050000000003total: 0type: "error"__proto__: ProgressEventheaders: Headers_headersMap: Mapsize: (...)__proto__: Map<entries>[0]No Entries__proto__: Objectstatus: 200statusText: "Ok"type: 3url: null__proto__: ObjectarrayBuffer: ()blob: ()constructor: Response(responseOptions)arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context.
    at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:3:14)]caller: (...)length: 1name: "Response"prototype: Object__proto__: ()<function scope>json: ()arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 0name: ""prototype: Object__proto__: ()<function scope>text: ()__proto__: Object
```

Comment: What is the current status code you receive for your request? Just a second callback when subscribing to get this hint...

Comment: Add the error handler in your subscribe `.subscribe((res) => console.log("res", res), err => console.log('error', err));` to see what error you're getting.

Comment: hi..please seen my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a cross origin problem:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://url/login/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

You need to allow your client domain on the server side by using proper headers